# Convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python3, that form a pyramid-type structure of 5 levels top, and i need to convert to a dictionary of dictionary in base to one value.
for example the list:

```
[   {'data': 'data', 'name': 'exampleName2', 'referal': 'exampleName1'},
{'data': 'data', 'name': 'exampleName3', 'referal': 'exampleName2'},
{'data': 'data', 'name': 'exampleName4', 'referal': 'exampleName3'}]
```

need to be converted to(every refered list could contain any number of items):

```
{   'data': 'data',
'name': 'exampleName1',
'refered': [   {   'data': 'data',
                   'name': 'exampleName2',
                   'refered': [   {   'data': 'data',
                                      'name': 'exampleName3',
                                      'refered': [   {   'data': 'data',
                                                         'name': 'exampleName4',
                                                         'refered': [   ]}]}]}]}
```

I could do a lot of for and while loops, but i think there is a fast method. My method at the moment is:

```
try:
    porOrdenar = LISTADO
    ordenados = []
        while len(porOrdernar) > 0:
            n = 0
            while n < len(porOrdernar):
                if porOrdernar[n]["referal"]=="uno":
                    ordenados.append(porOrdernar[n])
                    porOrdernar.pop(n)
                for element in ordenados:
                    unirReferidos(porOrdernar, n, element1)
                    for element1 in element["referidos"]:
                        unirReferidos(porOrdernar, n, element1)
                        for element2 in element1["referidos"]:
                            unirReferidos(porOrdernar, n, element2)
                            for element3 in element2["referidos"]:
                                unirReferidos(porOrdernar, n, element3)
            n +=1
except IndexError:
    pass

def unirReferidos(porOrdernar, n, element3):
    if porOrdernar[n]["referal"] == element3["name"]:
        element3["refered"].append(porOrdernar[n])
        porOrdernar.pop(n)
```

I need to convert the dictionary to a json object, for that i preferer a dictionary.

Comment: Please format your existing and desired data examples with `pprint`, it will vastly improve readability.

Comment: Honestly, you don't want to do this with a dictionary. Part of the reason you are having so much trouble with this is that it's the wrong data type for this. You want something like a linked list or a queue.

Comment: Also, please make sure the desired result is syntactically correct. The quotes in you desired dict are all messed up.